# When click at the edge of input element in Chrome, inner content will scroll and select some content

Tags: html, google-chrome, input, browser

This happens in lastest Chrome, and my version is 55.0.2883.75 m (64-bit).

[This is a gif about this problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5sbM.gif)

And if you hold on mousedown ,it will select all the content on the right. Is this a bug of Chrome or a new "function"? But I want to stop this and make it performs what it performs before.

Comment: I think its some sort of chrome extension. Open incognito window of chrome and try again.

Comment: @SankarRaj sorry, it still occur

Comment: this also happens with any scrollable element. For example, try to click on partially visible text on the bottom of this very page. Chrome will select some text and scroll up the page.